# JavaFX - How to get a random thumbnail / picture from a movie?

Tags: javafx, media, preview

Is it possible to get a random picture from a video in JavaFx?
I know there is a `snapshot()` method provided by `MediaView`, but the thing is, I wanna get a picture of each video I loaded **BEFORE** it was displayed in `MediaView`.

I need those pictures to create previews in my library, hopefully you realize what is meant.

Thanks in advance for any idea or suggestion :)

Comment: Why not cache a `snapshot()` when the item is added to the library? An interactive feature to choose a new `snapshot()` would be nice, too.

Comment: That's a nice idea though but I don't need it :-)
Can you give me an example with "cache-ing" a picture?

Comment: I don't have one, but you might look at having a `List<MediaItem>`, where `MediaItem` aggregates a `MediaView` and an `ImageView`.